# Filling subarray with elements that fulfill certain condition - java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string array like:

```
String FileContent = "2017-04-03, 11:25, 2; 2017-04-02, 11:30, 8; 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9";
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract the elements that fulfill a certain criteria, let's say we need to pick the array members of a given date.

```
String[] SplittedContent = FileContent.split("\\s*;\\s*");

String date= "2017-04-03";

for (int i = 0; i < SplittedContent.length; i++)


            if (SplittedContent[i].contains(date))
                {
                 String [] MatchingContent = null;

                 MatchingContent[i]= SplittedContent[i];    

                }
```

It gives me an error for this line: MatchingContent  [i]= SplittedContent[i];
Can somebody pls help?

Comment: Replace `String [] MatchingContent = null;` with `List<String> MatchingContent = new ArrayList<>();` and then use `MatchingContent.add(SplittedContent[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an ith element in an array that is *null*. You need to initialize a new list and then add items to it:

```
String FileContent = "2017-04-03, 11:25, 2; 2017-04-02, 11:30, 8; 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9";
String date= "2017-04-03";
String[] SplittedContent = FileContent.split("\\s*;\\s*");
List<String> MatchingContent = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < SplittedContent.length; i++)
    if (SplittedContent[i].contains(date))
    {
        MatchingContent.add(SplittedContent[i]);
    }
System.out.println(MatchingContent);
// => [2017-04-03, 11:25, 2, 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9]
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/cR260U)

Note that it might be more appropriate to check if a value *starts with* the dae with

```
if (SplittedContent[i].startsWith(date))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Another way to collect the matches would be to use a regex to directly match the substrings you need:

```
String FileContent = "2017-04-03, 11:25, 2; 2017-04-02, 11:30, 8; 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9";
String date= "2017-04-03";
List<String> MatchingContent = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(date + "[^;]+").matcher(FileContent);
while(m.find()) {
    MatchingContent.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(MatchingContent);
// => [2017-04-03, 11:25, 2, 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9]
```

See [another Java demo](http://ideone.com/s2FkXd).

The `[^;]+` negated character class (`[^...]`) matches any 1+ characters other than `;`.